# How do I cleanly check if a ruby hash has a value before executing code in ERB?

Tags: html, ruby, erb

I have an XML object that's loaded into a Ruby hash. The goal is to display some complex XML from a web service in a webpage.

The tricky thing is the XML can look different depending on what XML data is returned from the web service.

I have ERB code that looks like this...

```
...
<p>Name:</p><%= @some_hash['root']['data']['name'] %>
<table>
<tr><td><span class="label">Total:</span><%= @some_hash['root']['data']['subdata'] %></td></tr>
<tr><td><span class="label">Rate:</span><%= @some_hash['root']['data']['subdata1'] %></td></tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Column A</th>
      <th>Column B</th>
    </tr>

  <% @some_hash['root']['data']['subdata2'].each do |value| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= @value['A'] %></td>
      <td><%= @value['B']  %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
 </table>
...
```

I put the "@" in front of the variables to check for nil. That didn't do much. I'm not sure if this is the best approach. How do I cleanly iterate through the ERB and only execute if the value exists?

Comment: Which value might be missing and what's your expected result for present or missing value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hash#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) and the [safe navigation operator](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/NEWS-2_3_0.html) will do this:

```
<% if subdata = @some_hash&.dig('root', 'data', 'subdata') %>
  <tr><td><span class="label">Total:</span><%= subdata %></td></tr>
<% end %>
```

`dig` will attempt to extract the nested value, returning nil if any part of it is unavailable. The safe navigation operator `&.` prevents the NoMethodError when calling `.dig` if `@some_hash` is nil.

Comment: would this be reliable without the if? Like <tr><td><span class="label">Total:</span><%= @some_hash&.dig('root', 'data', 'subdata') %></td></tr>.

Answer (score 2):

Use a helper

```
def data_table(source)
  if subdata = source&.dig('root', 'data', 'subdata')
    h.content_tag :table do
      h.content_tag :tr do
         h.content_tag :td do
           h.content_tag :span, 'Total:'
           subdata
         end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### erb

```
<p>Name:</p><%= @some_hash['root']['data']['name'] %>
<%= data_table(@some_hash) %>
```

Comment: I really like this idea. I keep getting "wrong number of arguments" with the code above. I think it's in the h.content_tag :span?

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if subdata = (@some_has || {}).dig('root', 'data', 'subdata') %>
  <tr><td><span class="label">Total:</span><%= subdata %></td></tr>
<% end %>
```